# Change delay of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutorService without terminating the service

Tags: java, daemon, scheduler, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

As the name suggests, we have a daemon framework which uses Executor service to schedule daemons.

```
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable 
     command, long initialDelay, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
```

At runtime, I want to change the delay between two runs of the `Runnable` class, without terminating our application.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can you not do nothing when it doesn't need to run?

Comment: I want to change the schedule depending on some other parameter. Today, I am running it at the interval of 2 hours, tomorrow, I want to run it every hour (say, I need more computation, just an example).

Comment: So if you run it every hour and skip every second hour when you need to, would that do it?

Comment: Yes, that will. But I don't know the minimum granularity in advance and it will make it quite complex with this logic. Looks like, there is no straight forward way.

Comment: The only other option is to cancel the task and add it with a different schedule. You can do this fairly simply with two calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know the minimum granularity in advance

In that case you need to cancel the schedule and add it again.

```
private Future future = null;
private long periodMS = 0;

public void setPeriod(long periodMS) {
   if (future != null && this.periodMS == periodMS) return;
   if (future != null) future.cancel(false);
   scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, periodMS/2, periodMS, TimeUnit.MILLI_SECONDS);
}
```

or you can make the task reschedule itself.

```
private long periodMS;

public void start() {
  scheduledExecutorService.schedule(this, periodMS, TimeUnit.MILLI_SECONDS);
}

public void run() {
   try {
       task.run();
   } catch(Exception e) {
       // handle e
   }
   start();
}
```

This way the period can change every time it is run.